# Create a required select to toggle another hidden select with contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, select, drop-down-menu, contact-form-7

I have a form built using contact form 7. I have 2 selects.
The first selects a number 1-7. It also has an option for "Not Started". If, an only if, "Not Started" is selected, then the second select should be made visible.

Select 1 = number
Select 2 = startYear

startYear is hidden to begin with.
If number option is selected as "Not started" then startYear select appears
Both fields should be required when visible. And startYear should be reset if number is changed to a different value

Below is what I have and it operates mostly as it should except for a couple of things. Primarily the fields are not required and can be submitted blank. Also, while the second select correctly appears and disappears, the value is not reset.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">
 <p style="margin-bottom: 0;">Primary(at present)
      <select name="number" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" onchange="showdiv(this.value);">
                <option disabled selected value></option>
                <option value="0">Not yet started</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
      </select>
 </p>
</div>

<div id="div-two" style="display:none;">
      <p>Year due to start, if not yet started[select startyear include_blank id:startyear "2018/19" "2019/20" "2020/21" "2021/22"]</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showdiv(element){
document.getElementById("div-two").style.display = element==0?"inline-block":"none";
} 
</script>
```

Comment: try this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/

Comment: That works great, the only issue is that it doesn't reset the value of select 2 if it is re-hidden. This means that the form submits both a number from select 1 and a year for select to which would be misleading. It should only submit a year if the first select says not started. Any way to fix that instead perhaps?